# asyncpg interface error server expects 2 arguments for this query, 1 was passed

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py, asyncpg

Tried changing from aiosqlite to asyncpg, and kept running into

```
InterfaceError: the server expects 2 arguments for this query, 1 was passed
HINT:  Check the query against the passed list of arguments.
```

Here are some of the problematic lines

```
data = await bot.db.fetch('''SELECT study_time FROM guildData WHERE guild_id = ($1) AND user_id = ($2)''', (ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id))

await bot.db.execute('''UPDATE guildData SET study_time = study_time + ($1) WHERE guild_id = ($2) AND user_id = ($3)''', (total_mins, ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id))

async with bot.db.execute(f'''SELECT user_id, study_time FROM guildData WHERE guild_id = ($1) ORDER BY study_time DESC LIMIT ($2) OFFSET ($3)''', (ctx.guild.id, entries_per_page, entries_per_page*(current-1),)) as cursor:
```

Checked the reference and couldn't figure out what it should be changed to...?

Comment: Well from here [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html) it looks like the arguments for the parameters are not supposed to be in a tuple. Instead something like ` ... user_id = ($2)''', ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver just tried that out and it fixed the arguments problem, but showed up with OverflowError: value out of int32 range :(

Comment: Then you have a type mismatch with one of the argument values and the field it is going in. You need to find which query is tripping this by running one at a time. Then the argument/column combination that is at fault. Looking at the Postgres logs might help.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver! Turns out guild_id and user_id were out of range, had to typecast to bigint.

Comment: I keep running into syntax error for 
`async bot.db.execute('''INSERT INTO guildData(guild_id, user_id, study_time) VALUES($1, $2, 0) ON CONFLICT (guild_id, user_id) DO NOTHING''', ctx.guild_id, ctx.author.id)`

What is the correct way of writing this?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with your original question, please create a new question for it. When you do include the syntax error message.